# Are items in Vuex with Nuxt being crawled?

Tags: vue.js, seo, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm planning on storing the majority of the texts for my blog in vuex for fast loading speed. Is this a good idea especially for SEO or should i create individual routes for all posts? I definitly do not know alot about SEO and I'm also new to vue/nuxt, before I've used mostly vanilla javascript.

Comment: for seo yea, for speed and maintaneability meh. nuxt offers an module to write blogs on a static page that will be pre rendered. https://nuxtjs.org/blog/creating-blog-with-nuxt-content i also use the same nuxt module on my blog https://blogxon.com and it works very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but its defenetly not recommended to do it like that.

Nuxt offers a good module for writing blogs https://nuxtjs.org/blog/creating-blog-with-nuxt-content

Works for static sites too. They get pre-rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the resource! What exactly are the benefits saving the information in the API compared to saving generall information in Vuex and each specific posts in an own Componenet. Sorry if this questions seems basic, web dev is most definitly my biggest weakpoint ^^

Comment: @jonithani123 well if you save it in the vuex store like lets say 10 blogs and eath blog has minimum 1000 words in it your users will always load all 10 together witch is pretty damn slow after a while. vuex is made for UI states like toggeling an sidebar, or saving some information like web tokens things like that not blog posts. they are usually saved on an database or like in the nuxt module they are pre-rendered during the build.

Comment: @jonithani123 also make the question: what if you want to have somehing bold? or you want an h2 or h3 tag? or what if you want to add links and images into your blog post? you will have a hard time with only vuex. with nuxt-content module you have an [markdown editor](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) witch converts your text to html elements

Comment: Yea you're right, using an API also helps with scaling the blog easily and I used vue for this to minimize effort for later in the first place and using markdown later will be especially easy. Thanks alot for your input!

Answer (score 1):

If you’re wondering about Google’s ability to see the content, I wouldn’t worry. I’ve tested a number of similar situations and even when data is pulled in via an external API, Google has been happy to wait a little while to see how the page renders and crawl the result.

However if you’re worried, just generate your component data using `asyncData` or `fetch`. Either will run **before** your template is rendered, so you can grab your data and make it available before page load.

```
export default {
  async asyncData({ store }) {
    return {
      blogData: store.state.blogs.find(blog => blog.id === 1)
    }
  }
}
```

[Nuxt asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/api/)

Comment: Thats nice, I'll probably still use routes since without them google won't be able to rank my individual pages right?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use VueX to store the blog posts, especially if you are using all static content.

Nuxt has a wonderful package, [nuxt content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/) that is designed for this. It used markdown pages for blog posts.

Then I would use the [nuxt seo package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-seo) to super charge the SEO of your site. With it, you can easily set your default site SEO settings like Twitter handle and image. Then you can update the social media images for each blog posts you have, getting that data directly from `nuxt content`.